# How to create telnet client with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet, python-asyncio

First I should say I am completely new to asyncio or its' paradigm.

So I am trying implement asyncio (python 3.4) client with `asyncio.open_connection()` able to send requests on tcp socket (telnet) and read it's responses and listen to what other side may send in the same time.

In other words I need bi-directional communication which I am initializing, therefore I am client. Yet all examples I found so far using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` were forced to break loop after reading empty line. Also I need somehow deal with if incoming message (every message is exactly one line) is response to previouse request or original message of other side.
I was thinking something like this might work.

```
class MyHandler:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def connect(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = asyncio.open_connection('localhost', 2020)

        while True:
            msg = self.reader.readline()
            if msg is None:
                asyncio.sleep(1)
                continue
            self.handle_msg(msg)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def request(self, msg):
        self.writer.write(msg)
        return self.reader.readline()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = MyHandler()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(h.connect)
    loop.close()
```

I've written this code only during creating this question. Now that I start run it, it fails even before getting to main point. Somehow `loop.run_until_complete(h.connect)` fails with `TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required`

Comment: Why would the server send data that is not part of a reply to a previous request?

Comment: Because the protocol is not well designed and meant only asi two point communication.

Comment: Ok, biggest problem was my wrong understanding of asyncio library, secondary incompatible docs to my lib's version. What I did'nt get is I can create as many tasks as I want and set them pending with asyncio.ensure_future or asyncio.async (depending on the lib's version) then run event loop.

Comment: Have a look at the new [asyncio user documentation](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is still being built but there is a few of examples that might help you (written for python 3.5).

Answer (score 1):

`h.connect` is a function, whereas `h.connect()` is a coroutine. this means the correct code would be:

```
class MyHandler:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def connect(self):
        self.reader, self.writer = asyncio.open_connection('localhost', 2020)

        while True:
            msg = yield from self.reader.readline()  # Yield from since it's a coroutine
            if msg.strip() is None:
                yield from asyncio.sleep(1)  # Also a coroutine
                continue
            self.handle_msg(msg)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def request(self, msg):
        self.writer.write(msg)
        return (yield from self.reader.readline()) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = MyHandler()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(h.connect())
    loop.close()
```